# how to hide table-column in lotus notes form?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h1Zp.png)
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kQYd.png)
ex. i have 2 column in this table if i write "if i = 1 then hide column 2" and when i = 1 , they hide only text, not hide table-column how can i hide all? thank you!
i weak in English.

Comment: ex. i have 2 column in this table
if i write "if i = 1 then hide column 2" and when i = 1 , they hide only text, not hide table-column

how can i hide all?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hide when has to include the whole column not only one cell.

Comment: thank you sir. can you share your idea about 2 part/column in the form please?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have full control of rows/cells hiding, you might want to write your own table in plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to hide a table column when using the Notes client. 
If you're going to display the table in a web browser then you could easily hide with css.

I currently am able to "hide" a column but it's for a very specific use case which is probably not helpful to you but may be to others. I would only use this if it's the last column in the table, the contents are there for programmatic control (buttons, etc) or non-essential information, and you're hiding for preview/read/print purposes.

Do the following on all cells of the column:

1. Define the hide-when
2. Set the border width to 0
3. Set the cell color to white (or whatever your form's background color is)

Of course, by doing this the border width and color will always be the same. There's no way to programmatically change those.